# Results differ whether using a list or a numpy array in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, classification, scikit-learn

I have a dataset, `data`, and a labeled array, `target`, with which I build in scikit-learn a supervised model using the k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm.

```
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier()
neigh.fit(data, target)
```

I am now able to classify my learning set using this very model. To get the classification score :

```
neigh.score(data, target)
```

Now my problem is that this score depends on the type of the `target` object.

- If it is a python list, that is, created using `list()` and filled in with `target.append()`, the score method returns 0.68.
- If it is a numpy array, created using `target = np.empty(shape=(length,1), dtype="S36")` (it contains only 36-character strings), and filled in with `target[k] = value`, the score method returns 0.008.

To make sure whether results were really different or not, I created text files that list the results of

```
for k in data:
    neigh.predict(k)
```

in each case. The results were the same. 
 
**What can explain the score difference ?**

Comment: What happens if you specify the array's shape as (length) only? So that its shape will be (length,) and not (length, 1)?

Comment: @Harel, Thank you! That solved the problem. But I don't really understand why, how did you think about it ?

Comment: Nothing like experience... there's a difference in numpy between two-dimensional arrays with one dimension size = 1 and one-dimensional arrays. While they are often used interchangeably, they are not identical, and in this case this slight difference produced a problem. Is it ethical to ask for an upvote on my original comment? :)

Comment: @Harel, would love to, but not enough reputation to upvote..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Harel spotted the problem, here's the explanation:

```
np.empty(shape=(length, 1), dtype="S36")
```

creates an array of the wrong shape. scikit-learn estimators almost invariably want 1-d arrays, i.e. `shape=length`. The fact that this doesn't raise an exception is an oversight.